# retaining dropdown selection on page reload in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown list on a page like this:

```
<div id="dropdowndosen-lvl1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active" id="btntab5" runat="server"><a href="Add Dosen.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Dosen</a></li>
            <li id="btntab6" runat="server"><a href="Data Dosen.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Data Dosen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSOPo.png)

When a user makes a selection, the current page is refreshed like this [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO09A.png), but how do I keep the user's selection visible in the list after the page refresh? In other words, I don't want the list to rollback to its default selected value.

Please Help Me.

Comment: show us what you have tried till now

Answer (score 1):

try this example
first choose car from the list, and then click "choose" button
after that reload the page or close it and open it again, the car you have choosed in first part has a orang background

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function getname(){
    var car = document.getElementById("cars").value;
    localStorage.cars = car;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=localStorage.cars;
  }

  function colorize(){
    document.getElementById(localStorage.cars).style.background = "orange";
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="colorize()">
  <select name="cars" id="cars">
    <option id="volvo" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option id="saab" value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option id="fiat" value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option id="audi" value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="getname()">choose</button>
  <hr>
  <a id="result"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by getting the URL path and selecting the appropriate `a` tag which has that path in its `href` and settings its parent `li` class to `active`.

Sample code is given below.

```
   $(function(){
         $('ul.nav').find('li').removeClass('active'); // to remove hardcoded active class
         var activeAnchor = $('ul.nav').find('a[href="' + location.pathname + location.search + '"]');
         $(activeAnchor ).parent('li').addClass('active');

         //below script is if at all you have sub menus too
         if ($(activeAnchor).closest(".submenu").length > 0) {
           $(activeAnchor).closest('ul').parent('li').addClass('active').addClass('open').closest('ul').parent('li').addClass('open');
           $(activeAnchor).parent('li').addClass('active');
           $(activeAnchor).closest('ul').removeAttr('style').removeClass('nav-hide');
          }             
   });
```

Comment: Can you give me more explanation in html? Sorry i am still newbie in html